# Block UI Jquery plugin for a specific DIV

Tags: jquery-plugins, html, blockui

Anyone knows a JQuery plugin for BlockUI that allows blocking a specific DIV, not just the whole page. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it thru [blockui](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#element) plugin

Comment: Wasn't quick enough! @Andrew beat me with the same answer. :)

Answer (score 10):

You can do this natively with BlockUI: http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#element

```
$('div.test').block({ message: null })
```

Comment: How about if I want to block everything *except* one div. I tried $('div.grid_12').not('#mydiv').block({ message: null }); and everything still gets blocked.

Comment: @codecowboy: Seems like that'd be a good candidate for a new question `:)`

Answer (score 2):

```
$.blockUI({
  message: $("#divid"),

  css: {
    position: 'absolute',
  }
});
```