# BlockUI throws " has no method 'blockUI' " error when blocking specific DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-blockui

I've been using BlockUI to block the whole page, and it has been working fine like this:

```
$.blockUI()
```

but when I try to block a specific DIV (following  [Block UI Jquery plugin for a specific DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933086/block-ui-jquery-plugin-for-a-specific-div) ) like this

```
$('#my-div').blockUI()
```

It throws this error:

> TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'blockUI'

I thought maybe it's a conflict with jquery's $ so I changed the $ to J with noConflict like this

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict(true);
...
j.blockUI();              // <--- this one works
j('#my-div').blockUI();   // <--- this one doesn't work
$.blockUI();              // <--- this one doesn't work, so $ is not used
```

So this rules out a jQuery conflict. So any idea what is causing this?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#element) says that the syntax for blocking a single element is just `block` not `blockUI`

Try

```
$("#my-div").block();
```

Comment: thank you!!! totally missed it, no idea why they would change the name of the method though

Comment: @MartinMassera, no problem. If this solved your problem please don't forget to mark it as the answer by clicking on the checkmark.